# changes php.ini file are being ignored

Tags: php, server, apache2

I am having a hard time with this. 
I am trying to increase

```
post_max_size = 90M
upload_max_filesize = 50M
```

but my info.php is still showing default values 20M

I have tried many solutions available but no success. 
One of those were: /questions/14327409/changes-to-upload-max-filesize-in-ubuntu-php-ini-will-not-take-effect

First answer seem to work for people but it would not work for me. 
I created 30-user.ini file with these values but no luck. 
(I checked correct path for config directory I double checked)

I am using ubuntu 16 server and php7.0 
I restarted apache2 but not sure how to restart php, if thats required too.

Maybe putting those values into .htaccess file would help? but not sure how syntax should look like.

Comment: is this a production server? if so, is this a shared server?

Comment: Make sure it is loading the correct php.ini. Ubuntu will load the php.ini under the bin/apache2 folder..  not in the bin/php folder. So double check the phpinfo() which php.ini it loaded, then edit the correct file

Comment: Which `php.ini` file are you modifying? There are often multiple files, which affect changes either for the server (apache2 for instance) for the terminal (CLI).

Comment: Yes it is, it is not shared server. Server is loaded with correct php.ini file in which changes are written. Still dont work. Changes are now written in php.ini file which is being loaded by apache2 and in user.ini file too. Nothing works.

Comment: It doesn't say much when you say you're editing your "*correct php.ini*" file. Which php-version is loaded in `etc/apache2/mods-enabled/`? You should find it by typing `find /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ -name "php*"` in your terminal.

Comment: output: 
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.conf

php7.0, according to phpinfo. I assume it loads correct file

Comment: I am asking because the CLI and apache2 can run different versions of php, and therefore use different php.ini files.

Comment: how about file /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini ? Should I make changes there?
anyway, in this config values are set 8M and phpinfo shows vaule 20M so I reckon this is not the file.

Answer (score 0):

it might not be ideal solution, but as I could not get changes in php.ini file to work,
I added .htaccess file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
php_value post_max_size 105M
```

and it appear to be working now. 
I still don't know why it would not work directly in php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using php 7.0 or php 7.0-fpm...
Using php-fpm, it is not enough to restart apache, you have to restart php-fpm.

For example, on an Ubuntu 20.04 server and php 7.4 fpm, i had to

```
/etc/init.d/php7.4-fpm restart
```

in order for my php.ini to get obeyed.